# PHP sessions won't stay registered

Tags: php, session

I recently upgraded to php 5.3 and have been experiencing a few issues.

The main one being most of my sessions don't stay registered. Users are still able to login and stay logged in, however any other sessions I set disappear.

I am printing the $_SESSION array on every page and it's empty.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running `session_start` ?

Comment: Code or it didn't happen

Comment: Yes, session_start is including on top of every page.

Comment: Are there any major changes in PHP 5.3 regarding Sessions?

Comment: @Mchl I couldn't possibly post any of the code. It's way too lengthy. My sessions simply don't stay registered.

Comment: Have you looked at session_set_cookie_params() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php. Try setting the timeout, path & domain to see if it helps?

Comment: There are no changes in 5.3 regarding session handling. Perhaps you should try to write a short code, that would show this issue you're experiencing, and then you could show it to us? Without that, there's hardly anything we can advise.

Comment: This is really odd. It worked fine prior to 5.3. A simple test code works fine.

Comment: are you using any frameworks? I know prado framework had some issues with the 5.3 PHP upgrade, had to downgrade to 5.2.10 and PIN the version on Ubuntu

Comment: I am not using any frameworks. I am going insane. It's not passing any Sessions from page to page. *sighs*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow missed the fact I was going from HTTP to HTTPS. silly me.

Comment: +1 for this answer which shows that you're a human (failing is human). -1 for your question without code example.

Comment: I would also like to add the php version I am using is patched with suhosin. After tweaking suhosin a little, I am back to normal!